# Reactive forms: change detection on invisible items

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

In the following plunk, I get a change detection error:

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'.
>   Current value: 'false'

http://plnkr.co/edit/pyA3fEMO4QmeWz9PUaqx?p=preview

It is a simple form wizard with 3 pages using Angular 2 RC4 reactive forms. The key is that a field on the form that is currently not visible (in this case the 2nd page) is modified asynchronously from a HTTP request. Once the page containing the field is shown, the valid attribute of the page changes behind the back of Angular. The next button of the wizard triggers the error:

```
<button *ngIf="currentPage < cPages - 1" [disabled]="!pageValid()" (click)="next()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>

pageValid() {
    return this.form.controls['page' + this.currentPage].valid;
  }
```

Initially the form group is invalid because it is empty but `Validator.required` is given. Then the HTTP request sets the model of the input which makes it valid. However, Angular's change detection isn't run on the change of the `valid` property.

Is there a workaround? Is this actually a bug in Angular? I have to add that the error is actually intermittent, sometimes it works as desired, sometimes it throws.

Comment: It's not because it's invisible, it's because the ngModel is changing and your formcontrol doesn't like it.  If you remove the ngModel tags - you wont get any errors.  You can set values for formcontrol in the constructor, or by using formcontrol.updateValue().  And, you can retrieve a formcontrol value by using formcontrol.value.

Comment: The `ngModel` binding is intentional and in theory should be compatible with reactive forms. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: The problem is you are changing your model after the inital load, by using the HTTP call and setting last name.  You can't do this if the formcontrol is already instantiated

Comment: Could you elaborate why I can't do this please? I use 2-way binding which means Angular's change detection is supposed to watch those variables and a HTTP request is a prime source of change detection. The documentation says that reactive forms and `ngModel` can be used together. It looks like a bug to me.